# Visual Studio Unable to attach. An expected resource in the assembly manifest was missing

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, android-manifest, visual-studio-cordova

I got an error when I run a blank cordova project in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.
Build proses is complete and Chrome browser emulate the project, but an error message shown :

"Unable to attach. An expected resource in the assembly manifest was missing."

And Visual Studio Debugger not shown

update: I'm using 64bit machine, en-us language, 64bit chrome update version

Comment: It is a very low-level error produced by the verifier.  The component in the CLR that checks if the metadata of the assembly contains valid data.  It found a field with an initializer but the constants table in the metadata is missing the matching record.  You can't get help with it here.  Pretty unthinkable that the compiler you use has a bug like this, especially on a blank app.  Something wrong with your machine, probably.

Comment: Do you have any additional information on machine configuration? Specifically the version of Windows, 32 vs 64 bit, Windows and VS language would be most helpful. You may also want to verify that you have the latest version of Chrome (38).

Comment: Same bug, Win 7 64bit + VS 2013 update 4. Project was updated from MDHA to Cordova Tools, and debugging now didn.t work. Tried to 'Repair' Cordova Tools, Chrome is up to date. Blank Cordova Tools project - same issue.

Comment: Are either of you who are seeing this problem running a localized version of Visual Studio?  Even if you have the ENU language pack installed, if it was installed after the Cordova Tools, that could be the source of the problem.  We are investigating this and it would be helpful to understand the specifics of the environment it occurs in.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and I successfully resolved it.

My configuration:

- Windows 7 Pro 64 bits - French
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 (French Edition)
- CTP 3

What I did to solve the problem:

- First, I installed ENU Language Pack for Visual Studio to install English language
- Then, I switched the language of my Visual Studio to english
- Finally, I repaired my CTP 3.0 installation.

After that, I was able to debug application from my android device.

Another solution (but not suitable for everyone since it's required a MSDN Account) : using the Visual Studio 2015 Preview.